# Pub/Sub and Redis Clustering

Tags: redis

On this [link](http://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec) it says "The current implementation will simply broadcast all the publish messages to all the other nodes" and adds that it will be improved in future.

**For current implementation:** If loosing messages is not important; does it make sense to use redis for pub/sub for now? It looks like one instance is better to stop broadcast traffic. Because beside writes; reads should be propgated to other nodes too! (so that the client will not be notified twice.)

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, I don't think you missed any point. Redis Cluster is an on-going work, and this includes the specifications. The section about pub/sub is rather light and could probably be improved.

In Salvatore's proposal, a client is subscribed on a single instance (not to all of them), so when the publications are broadcasted to all instances, the client is only notified once. If the Redis instance is down, it is up to the client to subscribe on one of the surviving node of the cluster (any other).

Another possibility would have been to elect one node of the cluster as a unique pub/sub node, so that clients can publish and subscribe on this node only. But high-availability of the pub/sub service would be more difficult to support this way.